# saving webpages in android

Tags: java, android

Now I am doing an application to save webpages for offline reading. If our application is switched on then the pages we visited will be saved and we can open those pages in offline mode. Please provide the idea that how we can work on the application. Help me friends.

Comment: What do you mean with "work on the application"? What exactly is the problem and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Bevor...thanks for your response....My problem is how we can save a webpage in android[including image] and display the webpage when no internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

For downloading and saving a website, you could use [HTTPUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). The exception handling of this class will help you to control your application so you know when there is no internet connection.

For displaying a web site [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) is what you are searching for.